# ListFor enum flags MVC.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My model contains an enum with a flags attribute

```
[Flags()]
public enum InvestmentAmount
{
    [Description("£500 - £5,000")]
    ZeroToFiveThousand,

    [Description("£5,000 - £10,000")]
    FiveThousandToTenThousand,

    //Deleted remaining entries for size

}
```

I want to be able to display this in my view as a multiselectable List box.
Obviously the current helper for Listfor() doesn't support enums.

I've tried rolling my own but just receive

> The parameter 'expression' must evaluate to an IEnumerable when
>   multiple selection is allowed.

when it executes.

```
public static MvcHtmlString EnumListFor<TModel, TEnum>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TEnum>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
        Type enumType = GetNonNullableModelType(metadata);
        IEnumerable<TEnum> values = Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = from value in values
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = GetEnumDescription(value),
                                                Value = value.ToString(),
                                                Selected = value.Equals(metadata.Model)
                                            };

        // If the enum is nullable, add an 'empty' item to the collection
        if (metadata.IsNullableValueType)
            items = SingleEmptyItem.Concat(items);


        RouteValueDictionary htmlattr = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
        //htmlattr.Add("multiple", "multiple");
        if (expression.GetDescription() != null)
        {
            htmlattr.Add("data-content", expression.GetDescription());
            htmlattr.Add("data-original-title", expression.GetTitle());
            htmlattr["class"] = "guidance " + htmlattr["class"];
        }

        var fieldName = htmlHelper.NameFor(expression).ToString();

        return htmlHelper.ListBox(fieldName, items, htmlattr); //Exception thrown here
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the piece of code that throws the exception?

Comment: have you convert your enum list to List<SelectListItem>...?

Comment: Yes, ive added an example of what i'm currently doing.

Answer (score 3):

Check out my blog post on a helper method I created to do just this:

http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23

This enables you to do something like this:

```
//If you don't have an enum value use the type  
var enumList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor<MyEnum>();  

//If you do have an enum value use the value (the value will be marked as selected)  
var enumList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor(myEnumValue);
```

...which you can then use to build your multi list.

The helper class is as follows:

```
public static class EnumHelper  
{  
    //Creates a SelectList for a nullable enum value  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T? selected)  
        where T : struct  
    {  
        return selected == null ? SelectListFor<T>()  
                                : SelectListFor(selected.Value);  
    }  

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum type  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>() where T : struct  
    {  
        Type t = typeof (T);  
        if (t.IsEnum)  
        {  
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)).Cast<enum>()  
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });  

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name");  
        }  
        return null;  
    }  

    //Creates a SelectList for an enum value  
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct   
    {  
        Type t = typeof(T);  
        if (t.IsEnum)  
        {  
            var values = Enum.GetValues(t).Cast<Enum>()  
                             .Select(e => new { Id = Convert.ToInt32(e), Name = e.GetDescription() });  

            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", Convert.ToInt32(selected));  
        }  
        return null;  
    }   

    // Get the value of the description attribute if the   
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value.  
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)  
    {  
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());  

        if (fi != null)  
        {  
            DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =  
             (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(  
    typeof(DescriptionAttribute),  
    false);  

            if (attributes.Length > 0)  
            {  
                 return attributes[0].Description;  
            }  
        }  

        return value.ToString();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: This appears to only get the selectlist items, arguable the easiest problem to solve. The real trouble is binding the property such that it will write back when submitted.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to have been occurring because I was binding to just an "InvestmentAmount" where as it appears that ListFor checks if the model is a list.

I've had to change my model to a List and build in binding logic (Through AutoMapper) to convert from the flagged Enum to a List and back.

A nicer solution would be to create a generic HTML ListFor helper to do it. Which is the way I'll tackle it if I need it any more than once.